# decode screencap output raw to jpg

Tags: python

I need to encode ouput from screencap raw image to jpg. screencap is linux bult-in binary to screenshot screen. how to do this?

> codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 17

```
from PIL import Image

file = open("screen.raw", "r")

img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (1920, 1080), file.read(), 'raw', 'RGBX', 0, 1)

img.save("out.jpg", "JPEG", quality=80, optimize=True, progressive=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

with open('screen.raw', 'r') as file:
    buffer = file.read()

array = np.frombuffer(buffer, np.uint8).reshape(1080, 1920, 4)
image = cv2.cvtColor(array, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('out.jpg',image)
```